# Grip on a Kung-Fu staff (Bo) during training

Tags: kung-fu, bo-staff, grips

When training with a Kung-Fu staff, should I keep a strong grip on the staff or a loose grip?

*by training I mean doing basic staff exercises such as rotation or simple movements with the staff.

Answer (score 3):

For most staff work, grips change constantly to change range and direction of attacks or parries.   You have a tight grip when you expect impact, and naturally, you have to let go/slide/keep simple contact when you are moving your hands to change grip position.

If you are working from a form or in a class, this is something that should be shown to you.

If you are trying to play around and figure it out on your own... well, you might do well looking up some videos and books to see what your options are in terms of movement and not go fast or hard to start, especially if there is a chance the stick might fly out of your hands and hit anyone or anything that can break.

Comment: The tight grip when you expect impact and the loose one when you move/slide hands is true, but I am more concerned while doing staff forms, or staff basic exercises (such as spins). 

I tried searching for some literature, but that is a bit limited. I wanted to know whether there is a general rule while practicing with yourself, but I assume due to the vastness of Kung-Fu such a general rule might not exist.

Comment: Maybe consider modifying your question to be more specific?  If you can link photos or videos of specific movements or transitions, you can probably get better answers.

Comment: @surveyCorps  I don't think it matters whether you are practicing the basics, or not. You are constantly transitioning hand position and grip strength throughout most forms.